# Парсинг Json и присвоение параметров объекту класса

Tags: python

Есть класс:

```
class Conception:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.name = n
        self.delivery = ['Доставка', {'sum': 0, 'chq': 0, 'avg': 0}]
        self.notdelivery = ['Прилавок', {'sum': 0, 'chq': 0, 'avg': 0}]

    def setname(self, newname):
        self.name = newname

    def set_values_is_delivery(self, s, c, a):
        self.delivery[1]['sum'] = s
        self.delivery[1]['chq'] = c
        self.delivery[1]['avg'] = a

    def set_values_is_not_delivery(self, s, c, a):
        self.notdelivery[1]['sum'] = s
        self.notdelivery[1]['chq'] = c
        self.notdelivery[1]['avg'] = a

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Концепция: {0}\n''Доставка: {1}\n''Прилавок: {2}'. \
            format(self.name, self.delivery, self.notdelivery)
```

Есть json с данными:

```js
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "Conception":null,
         "Delivery.IsDelivery":"ORDER_WITHOUT_DELIVERY",
         "DishDiscountSumInt":0,
         "DishDiscountSumInt.average":0,
         "OpenDate.Typed":"2016-12-20T00:00:00",
         "UniqOrderId.OrdersCount":1
      },
      {  
         "Conception":"One",
         "Delivery.IsDelivery":"DELIVERY_ORDER",
         "DishDiscountSumInt":35125,
         "DishDiscountSumInt.average":5017.86,
         "OpenDate.Typed":"2016-12-20T00:00:00",
         "UniqOrderId.OrdersCount":7
      },
      {  
         "Conception":"One",
         "Delivery.IsDelivery":"ORDER_WITHOUT_DELIVERY",
         "DishDiscountSumInt":59594,
         "DishDiscountSumInt.average":425.67,
         "OpenDate.Typed":"2016-12-20T00:00:00",
         "UniqOrderId.OrdersCount":140
      },
      {  
         "Conception":"Two",
         "Delivery.IsDelivery":"ORDER_WITHOUT_DELIVERY",
         "DishDiscountSumInt":240,
         "DishDiscountSumInt.average":120,
         "OpenDate.Typed":"2016-12-20T00:00:00",
         "UniqOrderId.OrdersCount":2
      },
      {  
         "Conception":"Three",
         "Delivery.IsDelivery":"DELIVERY_ORDER",
         "DishDiscountSumInt":49422,
         "DishDiscountSumInt.average":4942.2,
         "OpenDate.Typed":"2016-12-20T00:00:00",
         "UniqOrderId.OrdersCount":10
      }
   ]
}
```

Есть json сообщения для мессенджера Slack:

```js
[
        {
            "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",
            "color": "good",
            "pretext": "__"
        },
        {
            "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",
            "color": "#4B1924",
            "author_name": "One",
            "author_icon": "http://unicodey.com/emoji-data/img-twitter-64/1f4e2.png",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "title": "No delivery",
                    "short": "true"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Delivery",
                    "short": "true"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Выручка",
                    "value": "24 000",
                    "short": "true"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Выручка",
                    "value": "24 000 руб.",
                    "short": "true"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Чеки",
                    "value": "24",
                    "short": "true"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Чеки",
                    "value": "24",
                    "short": "true"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Средний чек",
                    "value": "2 400",
                    "short": "true"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Средний чек",
                    "value": "1 000 руб.",
                    "short": "true"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Итого",
                    "value": "100000",
                    "short": "false"
                }
            ]
        },
         {
            "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",
            "color": "#9887C2",
            "author_name": "Two",
            "author_icon": "http://unicodey.com/emoji-data/img-apple-64/1f680.png",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "title": "No delivery",
                    "short": "true"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Delivery",
                    "short": "true"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Выручка",
                    "value": "24 000",
                    "short": "true"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Выручка",
                    "value": "24 000 руб.",
                    "short": "true"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Чеки",
                    "value": "24",
                    "short": "true"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Чеки",
                    "value": "24",
                    "short": "true"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Средний чек",
                    "value": "2 400",
                    "short": "true"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Средний чек",
                    "value": "1 000 руб.",
                    "short": "true"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Итого",
                    "value": "100000",
                    "short": "false"
                }
            ],
            "footer": "__",
            "ts": 123456789
        }

]
```

Нужно подставить данные из одного json в другой, где:

```
...
"author_name": "Conception.name()"
...
                {
                    "title": "Выручка",
                    "value": "Conception.set_values_is_delivery.s()",
                    "short": "true"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Чеки",
                    "value": "Conception.set_values_is_delivery.c()",
                    "short": "true"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Conception.set_values_is_delivery.a()",
                    "value": "2 400",
                    "short": "true"
...
```

Я вот сижу и думаю, а нужен ли тут class Conception вообще? Может можно как-то без него обойтись? Кто может предложить более простое решение задачи?

Comment: Создайте [mcve]

Comment: В питоне после парсинга json получаются стандартные структуры и типы питона -- dict, list, int, float, str и None
т.е. вы можете работать с этими данными и после из них сгенерировать строку json